# How to consume a LOB Adapter SDK-based design-time interfaces

Tags: wcf-lob-adapter

I'm trying to build a web-based GUI to consume custom [LOB Adapter SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb798128.aspx)-based connectors.
In particular, I would like to browse the metadata using the [IMetadataResolverHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb798128.aspx) interface.

I'm having two problems:

The first problem happens when trying to instantiate the custom adapter. My plan is to obtain an instance of the [IConnectionFactory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.servicemodel.channels.common.iconnectionfactory%28v=bts.80%29.aspx) interface, through which I could get a new [IConnection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.servicemodel.channels.common.iconnection%28v=bts.80%29.aspx) and connect to the target LOB system.

Since the most interesting methods in the [Adapter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.servicemodel.channels.common.adapter%28v=bts.80%29.aspx) base class are protected, I can only seem to succeed using reflection (please, see the sample code below).

The second problem happens when trying to browse the metadata from the target system. The method `Browse` on the [IMetadataResolverHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb798128.aspx) interface expects an instance of a [MetadataLookup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.servicemodel.channels.common.metadatalookup%28v=bts.80%29.aspx) object that I have no idea how to obtain.

Please, see the sample code below:

```cs
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var extension = new SqlAdapterBindingElementExtensionElement();
        var adapter = (Adapter) Activator.CreateInstance(extension.BindingElementType);

        var isHandlerSupportedMethodInfo = adapter.GetType().GetMethod("IsHandlerSupported", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
        var buildConnectionUri = adapter.GetType().GetMethod("BuildConnectionUri", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
        var buildConnectionFactory = adapter.GetType().GetMethod("BuildConnectionFactory", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);

        if (isHandlerSupportedMethodInfo == null || buildConnectionUri == null || buildConnectionFactory == null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Not a LOB adapter.");
            Environment.Exit(1);
        }

        var isHandlerSupportedTHandler = isHandlerSupportedMethodInfo.MakeGenericMethod(typeof(IMetadataResolverHandler));
        var isMetadataBrowseSupported = (bool)isHandlerSupportedTHandler.Invoke(adapter, new object[] { });

        if (!isMetadataBrowseSupported)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Metadata retrieval not supported.");
            Environment.Exit(1);
        }

        var bindingElement = (SqlAdapterBindingElement)adapter;
        bindingElement.AcceptCredentialsInUri = false;
        bindingElement.InboundOperationType = InboundOperation.TypedPolling;
        bindingElement.PolledDataAvailableStatement = "EXEC [dbo].[usp_IsDataAvailable]";
        bindingElement.PollingStatement = "EXEC [dbo].[usp_SelectAvailableData]";
        bindingElement.PollingIntervalInSeconds = 10;

        var binding = new CustomBinding();
        binding.Elements.Add(adapter);

        var parameters = new BindingParameterCollection();

        var context = new BindingContext(binding, parameters);

        var credentials = new ClientCredentials();
        credentials.UserName.UserName = "username";
        credentials.UserName.Password = "password";

        var address = (ConnectionUri) buildConnectionUri.Invoke(adapter, new []{ new Uri("mssql://azure.database.windows.net//SampleDb?InboundId=uniqueId")});

        var connectionFactory = (IConnectionFactory)buildConnectionFactory.Invoke(adapter, new object[] { address, credentials, context });
        var connection = connectionFactory.CreateConnection();

        connection.Open(TimeSpan.MaxValue);

        MetadataLookup lookup = null; // ??
        var browser = connection.BuildHandler<IMetadataBrowseHandler>(lookup);

        connection.Close(TimeSpan.MaxValue);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question, I figured it out by inspecting the code of the "Consume Adapter Service" wizard. The key is to use the `IMetadataRetrievalContract` interface which, internally, is implemented using up to three LOB-SDK interfaces, and in particular `IMetadataResolverHandler`.

Here is code that works without reflection:

```cs
var extension = new SqlAdapterBindingElementExtensionElement();
var adapter = (Adapter) Activator.CreateInstance(extension.BindingElementType);

var bindingElement = (SqlAdapterBindingElement)adapter;
bindingElement.AcceptCredentialsInUri = false;
bindingElement.InboundOperationType = InboundOperation.TypedPolling;
bindingElement.PolledDataAvailableStatement = "EXEC [dbo].[usp_IsDataAvailable]";
bindingElement.PollingStatement = "EXEC [dbo].[usp_SelectAvailableData]";
bindingElement.PollingIntervalInSeconds = 10;

var binding = new CustomBinding();
binding.Elements.Add(adapter);

const string endpoint = "mssql://azure.database.windows.net//SampleDb?InboundId=unique";
var factory = new ChannelFactory<IMetadataRetrievalContract>(binding, new EndpointAddress(new Uri(endpoint)));
factory.Credentials.UserName.UserName = "username";
factory.Credentials.UserName.Password = "password";

factory.Open();
var channel = factory.CreateChannel();
((IChannel)channel).Open();

var metadata = channel.Browse(MetadataRetrievalNode.Root.DisplayName, 0, Int32.MaxValue);

((IChannel) channel).Close();
factory.Close();
```